# JSON/JS- Getting JSON object name

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object consisting of three other objects of type array :

[image]

I want to get the text `samsung` out of that object and the rest of the objects. I have tried using a for in loop  but I am getting the keys `0, 1 , 2`.

```
for(brand in brands){
 console.log(brand)  // prints out `0, 1 , 2`
}
```

so I added another nested for in loop, but than I get `0, 0, 0` which are the keys within samsung, and other array objects within the rest of the objects.

What am i missing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `brands` is an array of objects, each object having one property. I would suggest to convert the data to a single object with multiple properties, then your code would work. If you can't, then you are looking for `Object.keys(brands[brand])[0]`.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your insightful comment. would you be kind enough to share/elaborate more on how I can convert it to single object ? thanks a heaps

Comment: You should build your data from the beginning so that it looks like `{'samsung': [...], 'otherbrand': [...], ...}`.

Comment: Ah! you mean rebuild.. in that case I can't, but will definitely keep this in mind! thanks

Comment: You can also convert the data structure, but that only makes sense if you are going to do more things than just list the brand names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(brands[brand])`, and, based on your example, you would want `Object.keys(brands[brand])[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is looping through the entire array, rather than the keys of an object.

```
var brand = brands[0];
for ( var i in brand )
  console.log( brand[i] ) // -> samsung
```

Or to get them all:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++){
    var brand = brands[i];
    for ( var i in brand )
      console.log( brand[i] ) // -> samsung
}
```

Comment: But this would only get the first brand name, not all brand names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
for(brand in brands[0]){
  console.log(brand);
}
```

assuming the name of the array to be brands

**EDIT**

For all the elements in the array brands

```
brands.forEach(function(v){
    for(brand in v){
      console.log(brand);
    }
});
```

Comment: But this would only get the first brand name, not all brand names.

Comment: If you need all brand names then loop over the brands array